# The meaning of 腹にマガジン巻く

Tags: translation, jargon

I have one more problem with the song [俺はやる](https://open.spotify.com/album/6fOCGZWnxLM470jA03azno) by Wanyudo.

The context is as follows (someone transcribed the full lyrics [here](https://pay-design.net/01/2019/05/27/%e8%bc%aa%e5%85%a5%e9%81%93-%e4%bf%ba%e3%81%af%e3%82%84%e3%82%8b-%e3%83%95%e3%83%aa%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b9%e3%82%bf%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab%e3%83%80%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b8%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3%e5%85%a5/#comment-122813), the link contains also a live performance of this song without the need for Spotify account):

> 高校を中退して赤落ちに入り
>   前科者に囲まれた酒盛りの毎日
>   20歳の元旦には包丁握ってた
>   **腹にマガジン巻いて**東京で生きてた

I don't get what he wants to say by 腹にマガジン巻いて. Otherwise I translate as:

> Dropped out of school, went behind bars,
>   Drank everyday with ex-cons,
>   With a knife in my hand I came of age,
>   Living in Tokyo ...

Is it some kind of jargon, or is it a direct meaning of putting a magazine (as a "booklet")  to protect one's abdomen?

Comment: Try taking a look at No.3 [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/207218/meaning/m0u/).

Comment: Like this. https://matome.naver.jp/odai/2141958911168328301/2141959379173003703

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これは不良・ヤクザまがいの生活を経験しつつも日本の大学に進学して最終的にラッパーになった輪入道本人の半生の歌のようです([ソース](http://mikiki.tokyo.jp/articles/-/13436))。なので恐らく、この「マガジン」とはマンガ・グラビア雑誌の[マガジン](https://yanmaga.jp/ym/)のことだと思います。腹部にグラビア雑誌を巻いてパンチやナイフなどから防御するというのは以前に本当にあった話のようです。

https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12149865107

> これは、昭和期のヤクザ達がよく使った防御手段です。ジャンプのような再生紙ではなく、写真雑誌。（ツルツルした写真のページは密度が非常に高い）
>
> 写真のページが多い雑誌を、腹や胸に入れ、細いベルトかサラシで固定するわけです。
> 密度の高い写真系の雑誌は、厚さが1㎝もあれば、それでナイフの刺突ぐらいはほぼ完全に無効化できます。

すぐ上に出てくる「包丁」という文脈とも合致します。

もちろんマシンガンの弾薬もマガジンと呼びますけど、いくらなんでもリアルな21世紀の東京でランボーみたいな格好で生活している人はいないでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。私も銃のマガジンというのはその前後歌詞に全く合わないと思っていました。隠語というより不良の秘技だそうですね。

Answer (score 1):

**Magazine** can have two quite separate meanings in English:

- a periodical publication containing articles and illustrations.
- a chamber for holding a supply of cartridges to be fed automatically to the breech of a gun.

And the same applies to the Japanese 外来語 word **マガジン** too:

- 雑誌
- (銃などの)弾倉

In the context of the song, the second meaning could be the most relevant, but it's just a wild guess.

BTW, performing a search for [多弾マガジン巻き](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E5%A4%9A%E5%BC%BE%E3%83%9E%E3%82%AC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%B3%E5%B7%BB%E3%81%8D&source=lnms&tbm=isch) yields some interesting results...